# Is AS-PATH attribute supported by all vendors and routers?

Tags: bgp

As a Mandatory attribute I wondered if this attribute is interoperable? I've looked around on the internet and can't seem to find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is mandatory, and required for loop prevention.  Any vendor implementing BGP will implement this attribute.  I have never seen a BGP implementation without this attribute.

Comment: Karl but is it INTEROPERABLE though? Do ALL routers support this attribute?

Comment: Yes, if the router supports BGP then this attribute will be implemented and will be interoperable with any other BGP implementation.